# Does Matter.js have accurate acceleration?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

Look at these images:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34260118/83951655-f5b84680-a7e7-11ea-805d-4b7b9a2a2690.png,
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34260118/83951665-023c9f00-a7e8-11ea-94b1-b0aba08fc4cc.png

As you can clearly see, from the demonstrations above, even though both falls have the same mass and starting height, they have different accelerations.

This can also be due to my code. But I'll show my code here:

Acceleration.js:

```
var time=0;
var startVel;
var endVel;

//Aliases
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    World  = Matter.World,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Body   = Matter.Body;

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");

var engine=Engine.create();
var renderer = Render.create({canvas:canvas, context:canvas.getContext("2d"), engine: engine });

//Resize
canvas.width=300;
canvas.height=300;

//Create bodies
var ball=Bodies.circle(canvas.width/2, 50, 25);
World.add(engine.world, ball);
World.add(engine.world, Bodies.rectangle(0, canvas.height, canvas.width*2, 100, {isStatic:true})); //Ground

function restart () {
    var mass=Number(document.getElementById("mass").value);

    //Reset info
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=`
        <p>The acceleration is</p>
        <h5>...</h5>
        <p>pixels on the y axis per millisecond</p>
        <br>
        <label for='mass'>Mass:</label>
        <input type="range" id="mass" value="`+mass+`" oninput="this.value=`+mass+`" step="10" min="1" max="150">
        <button>...</button>`;

    //Reset variables
    time=0;
    startVel=0;
    endVel=0;
    Body.setPosition(ball, {x:canvas.width/2, y:50});
    ball.mass=mass;

    //update
    var update=setInterval(()=>{
        Engine.update(engine); //Update the engine

        if (time==0) { // The start of the demo
            startVel=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ball.velocity));
        }

        if (ball.position.y>canvas.height-75) { //The ball is at the bottom
            endVel=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ball.velocity));
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=`
                <p>The acceleration is</p>
                <h5>` + (endVel.y-startVel.y)/time + `</h5>
                <p>pixels on the y axis per millisecond</p>
                <br>
                <label for='mass'>Mass:</label>
                <input type="range" id="mass" min="1" value="`+mass+`" step="10" max="150">
                <button onclick='restart()'>Restart</button>`;
            clearInterval(update);
        } else { // The ball is not at the bottom
            time+=10;
        }
    }, 10);
}

restart();

Render.run(renderer);
```

Acceleration.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PhySimX - Acceleration Demo</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.14.2/matter.min.js" integrity="sha256-Bmvb4pJWin8rqq3GnwPz/hxBtqXaMdZHJnHYlpRULa4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
        #canvas, #info {
            display:inline-block;
        }

        #info {
            border:3px solid black;
            position:relative;
            top:-110px;
            width:140px;
            height:295px;
        }

        #info p {
            margin:0px;
        }

        #info, canvas {
            position: relative;
            left: 35%;
        }

        body * {
            text-align:center;
        }

        button {
            cursor:pointer
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="location.href='acceleration-home.html'" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;">Back to the acceleration homepage</button>

    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <div id="info">
        <p>The acceleration is</p>
        <h5>...</h5>
        <p>pixels on the y axis per millisecond</p>
        <label for="mass">Mass:</label>
        <input type="range" id="mass">
        <button>...</button>
    </div>

    <script src="acceleration.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is Matter.js' acceleration not completely accurate?
I don't believe that my code is causing any error. To get the acceleration of the ball, I do the standard formula (endVelocity-startVelocity)/(timeEnd-timeStart)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your definition of time and matter.js definition of time is different. You are calculating frames with a value of `10` each frame (note: this is not milliseconds but a setInterval frame/tween). Matter.js is either using a different animation loop and is measuring frames in their loop or is measuring real-world clock time.

#### Why setInterval frames is not the same as milliseconds?

The delay period in setInterval is treated by the interpreter as the **minimum** time to wait before executing your script. However the script may not trigger exactly **on** the delay time. This means your script does not necessarily run every 10ms, it may be 11ms in one round then 10.2ms in the next round then 10.7ms in the round after that etc. Over time this introduces drift between your definition of time and real-world time.

If matter.js does what you are doing then their "clock" will also drift in relation to real-world time. When your clock is drifting and matter.js is drifting then both may or may not agree on how fast time is moving.

If matter.js calculates physics using real-world time then your drift against real-world clock time explains why you and matter.js don't agree.

In some cases `setInterval` may be delayed by **1 second (1000ms)** - most modern browsers do this when a tab goes out of focus to reduce javascript execution load. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified for other situations where the browser will refuse to follow your specified interval).

Comment: Thanks! However, I did sync Matter.js' update interval and my interval by using this function in my interval:
Engine.update(engine);

Comment: That's their update (frame) interval. Which leaves open the possibility that they calculate time using real-world clock. This is common in real-time game engines to avoid the game slowing down on slow machines or speeding up on fast machines. Instead of slowing down such physics engine will exhibit lag/stutter

Comment: Ok. Then what do you suggest I do?

Comment: I accounted for the drift by looking at something else but it still doesn't work.